# What controls (de)indenting when inserting a brace character?

Tags: indentation

Working on a C file, Vim correctly indents as I type. In Objective-C, however, it gets indentation right, but *de*indentation wrong for instance methods, unless I exit insert mode and use the `=` operator.

For example, if `|` is the cursor, in C I get:

```
int main()|
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
int main()
    |
```

type <kbd>{</kbd>

```
int main()
{|
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
int main()
{
    |
```

type <kbd>}</kbd>

```
int main()
{
}|
```

But in Objective-C, I get:

```
- (void)method
{|
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
- (void)method
{
    |
```

type <kbd>}</kbd>

```
- (void)method
{
    }
```

I have 'autoindent' on, 'smartindent' off, 'cindent' on, and 'cinkeys' is `0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e`

Comment: `smartindent` talks about it. Maybe you have an autocomand that turns on `cindent` when in a `.c` file so It doesn't work for your objective C files? I think if you turn `smartindent` on it should work. From `:h smartindent`: "When typing '}' as the first character in a new line, that line is
 given the same indent as the matching '{'."